# Get woocommerce price and return it to be used as a parameter

Tags: woocommerce, gravityforms

I have found a snippet and used it to get some event data but was wondering if there is a way to get selected woo prices to be returned so I can have them dynamically populate a field

```
/********************************************************************
Add tile cost parameter to Gravity Forms
********************************************************************/
add_filter('gform_field_value_tile_cost', 'my_tilecost_population_function');
function my_tilecost_population_function($value){
 return thewoocommerceprice;
}
```

Have tried a number of things but not working,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.